# Markdown in nested divs not being processed

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, markdown, jekyll, kramdown

I'm creating a theme using Bootstrap with jekyll and I'm running into a problem when creating content in markdown.
Ideally I'd like to structure my posts with Bootstrap grids like so:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-md-6" markdown="1">
  # Hello World
  </div>
</div>
```

However, the markdown isn't being processed here. It doesn't seem to work in nested HTML blocks.

Single level blocks will work:

```
<div markdown="1">
# Hello World
</div>
```

I'm using Kramdown and I can't see any examples similar to this in the docs.
I'm guessing maybe I need to create a plugin to do this?

Comment: I suspect you need to add `markdown=1` to each level of your raw HTML. When kramdown sees the outer div without the attribute set, it ignores everything inside and never sees the inner div with the attribute.

Comment: Thanks, I tired adding the attribute to each level, but that doesn't cause the markdown to be processed either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kramdown's documentation simply states regarding [stx style headers](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#atx-style)

> No spaces are allowed before the hash characters.

Therefore, you need to delete the indentation of your Markdown content within the `div` tag:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-md-6" markdown="1">
# Hello World
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small plugin to add liquid tags for the grid system [here](https://gist.github.com/jahnertz/0e26ddb9807c6e9c6f5253e67a1976dc)
(Heavily based on [this](http://www.glitchwrks.com/2017/07/25/jekyll-plugins) tutorial)

This doesn't really answer the question, but it does get the job done.